# Pandas Bar Graph: Side By Side (No X or Y axises shared)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[Two Bar Plots- Non side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFt3A.png)

Hi,
I am relatively new to Pandas and Python. I have been trying to get my two bar graphs to be displayed side by side instead of showing it one after another as it is in the image above. They do not share a y or x axis as they are separate independent variables. I would like to present it so that I can emphasize how closely related they are and that they are duplicate variables.

So far, I have looked at http://worksofscience.net/matplotlib/gridspec
where GridSpec is used to create different grids to plot in.
After creating two grids of equal size ax1 and ax2, I tried to add in the my two plots appended to their respective variables as with the code below

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=[15,8])
gs = GridSpec(100,100)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[:,0:50])
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[:,51:100])

#saving the plots in variables
waterpointtype=waterindep.waterpoint_type.value_counts().plot(kind='bar',title ='Waterpoint_Type')
#plt.show()
waterpointtypegroup = waterindep.waterpoint_type_group.value_counts().plot(kind='bar',title='Waterpoint_Type_Group')
#plt.show()
#plotting on those axes
ax1.plot(waterpointtype)
ax2.plot(waterpointtypegroup)

fig1.savefig('waterpointcomparison.png', format ='png', dpi =600)
plt.show()
```

However, I am ending up with 
**Index Error: index 51 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3** which I cannot make sense of. If you have a solution to this error or another way by which I can plot bar-graphs side by side, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the axes to the plot calls:

```
waterindep['waterpoint_type'].value_counts().plot(
    kind='bar',title='Waterpoint_Type', ax=ax1)
waterindep['waterpoint_type_group'].value_counts().plot(
    kind='bar',title='Waterpoint_Type_Group', ax=ax2)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
np.random.seed(2015)

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=[15,8])
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(100,100)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[:,0:50])
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[:,51:100])
waterindep = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100,2)), 
                          columns=['waterpoint_type', 'waterpoint_type_group'])
waterindep['waterpoint_type'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',title='Waterpoint_Type', ax=ax1)
waterindep['waterpoint_type_group'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',title='Waterpoint_Type_Group', ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

### [image]

Note that you could also use

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=[15,8], ncols=2)
ax1, ax2 = axs
```

instead of `gridspec.GridSpec` to create the axes. It will have 
better looking spacing between the axes "out-of-the-box".

Comment: thanks a lot. Works like a charm.
I have looked at .plot function on pandas and reaches to [http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis]and pyplot's  subplot [http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot].
By looking at just those two, I wouldn't know to add the ax parameter in the plot function without you telling me. What else can I do to get to those realizations? The obvious answer being asking here and researching more. But, anything else?

Comment: It's just experience. There is most definitely a question here on SO (which unfortunately I haven't been able to locate) which is solved by [passing the `ax` argument to `df.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). I learned this from someone else, and now you know the trick too.